# Separar y guardar informacion de un bloc de notas

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy creando una aplicacion que lea de un bloc de notas la siguiente informacion

> ESTATUS, No., FECHA HORA, CANTIDAD
>
> Entra a piso, 11, 2/15/2018 5:21:58 PM, 1
>
> Sale de piso, 11, 2/15/2018 5:26:39 PM, 1

y asi pues ya dependiendo del numero del gafet pero se registran entradas y salidas con hora y fecha y lo que quiero lograr es compararlos por ejemplo ver que entro el gafet 11 a las 5:21:58 PM y saber que salio a esa hora, y lo que e logrado hasta ahora es esto

```
string[] words;
        string name = "";
        DateTime fecha;
        int counter = 0;
        string line;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            name = dtFecha.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
            fecha = dtFecha.Value.Date;
        }

        private void dtFecha_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            fecha = dtFecha.Value.Date;
            name = fecha.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            name = name.Replace("/","_");
            label1.Text = name;
            line = "";
            try
            {
                            // Read the file and display it line by line.  
                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\RNUNEZ2\Desktop\data\"+name+".txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                    counter++;
                    words = line.Split(',');
                    foreach (string word in words)
                    {

                            richTextBox1.AppendText(word.Replace(" ", "") + "\n");


                    }

            }
                file.Close();
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Cantidad de datos recividos "+counter);

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error de lectura de datos por "+ ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

pero no se como separarlos por entrada y numero y luego compararlos con la salida y numero que esten mas cercana, intente en el for each poner unos if pero no supe resolverlo, para que se guarde por separado la informacion de cada renglon pero poder compararla con los demas, solo necesito saber como guardar los datos y poder aceder a ellos por el numero

Comment: mira para lo que quieres hacer te recomiendo con la lectura que crees una clase con los datos que lees de tu archivo y vayas añadiendo a una lista, luego cuando necesites consultarla haces uso de LINQ y te seria mucho mas facil

Comment: como ya cuenta con este arreglo string : `words = line.Split(',');` para acceder a ellos por número solo necesita  hacer esto: **ESTATUS** = `words[0]`, **No.** = `words[1]`, **FECHA HORA** = `words[2]`,  **CANTIDAD** `words[3]`, con eso obtiene como tal los valores separados por coma y los puede utilizar según

Comment: Te recomiendo usar alguna librería de las existentes para analizar archivos csv, por ejemplo esta [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper)